# How to write an entangled state in Strawberry Fields Quantum Computing Python Package?

Tags: programming, strawberryfields

In Strawberry Fields's own internet site they explain many kinds of states mathematically and then show how to implement the state in Python. Unfortunately I could not find how to implement a multi-mode state (e.g. $|0\rangle|1\rangle$).

Comment: The state you have written is not an entangled state. Do you mean you are wondering how to implement a state with more than one mode?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I want to implement a state more than one mode.

Comment: The section "State Preparation" in this tutorial might be what you're looking for https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/demos/run_blackbird.html (I also edited the question such that it says "mutli-mode" instead of "entangled")